# How to list every possible parent elements of a child element in xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

Given this data:

```
<root>
  <A>
    <A1 id="1">
        <elem>apple</elem>
    </A1>
  </A>

  <B>
    <B1 id="2">
        <elem>banana</elem>
    </B1>
  </B>

  <C id="3">
    <elem>grapes</elem>
    <C1></C1>
  </C>
</root>
```

How do I find out every possible parent elements of the element **elem**? So far, I am able to find out using -m option by:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//elem/..' -v 'concat(name(),"=",@id)' -n input3.xml
A1=1
B1=2
C=3

$
```

But how do I do the same using an **xpath** expression with -v ? For example, I can only refer to the parent's **id** attribute but not the parent element's name:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//elem/../@id' input3.xml
1
2
3
$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "name(//elem/..)" input3.xml
```

but that's only going to give you the name of the first match (xmlstarlet is an XPath 1.0 processor).

The only way to do this, like you found, is by matching (`-m`) first:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//elem/.." -v "name()" -n input3.xml
```

although I'd prefer a slightly different XPath:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//*[elem]" -v "name()" -n input3.xml
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I'll wait for a few more days lest different ideas comes up and then i'll accept this answer.

Comment: @daixtr - Please consider accepting this answer. If a better answer is posted you can always change which answer is accepted.